# Deploy Dotnet core Web api to AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-eks, webapi

I am deploying dotnet core web API 3.1 sample app to aws eks through kubectl get svc command I can able to get the external URL but the URL is not working,

The same deployment yml is working for a web applications but not working with web API. Do we need to do any additional configuration for web API projects?

Below is my yml deployment comments,

````
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apiddapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apiddapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apiddapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: xxxx.amazonaws.com/myapptestapi:v3
          name: apiddapp
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apiddapp
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: apiddapp
  type: LoadBalancer```

Many thanks in advance.
````

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? Does the yaml fail to apply? Does the yaml apply but the pods don't start up? Any pod logs?

Comment: No, able to create the service. But when I access the external URL in the browser it is displaying that the page cannot be load. I tried in postman also the same.

Answer (score 0):

try creating separate file for deployment and service. Create service first and see. I had the same issue but it works now. I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOROT9yMp44